# I want to make password generator loop with python

Tags: python, automation

I am trying to code a program which generates random passwords and saves it to a text file. I want program to keep running until it saves 100 random passwords to text file.

I have created the password generator
But whenever i try to save password its saves same password again and again.

Can anyone help me to make a loop for saving 100 random passwords to text file ?

Comment: Let's see what you've tried and someone will undoubtedly tell you where you're going wrong

Comment: Have a look at this guide - it will help you get more useful answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the same seed for your random function each time. Random functions in programming are deterministic: they will generate the same pseudo-random sequence every time you have the same starting conditions. To get a new sequence change the seed of the random function, which changes the starting conditions.

Comment: @OldBill A random anything generator that generates the same sequence every time is almost certainly caused by using the same seed at each run. This is a very likely a correct answer, though OP didn't really give enough details to be completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
import random

LEN_OF_PASSWORD = 5
NUM_OF_PASSWORDS = 100

for i in range(NUM_OF_PASSWORDS):
    password = ""
    for j in range(LEN_OF_PASSWORD):
        password += chr(random.randint(33, 126)) # Character range can be changed
    with open("passwords.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(password + "\n")
```

Comment: tnx its working;